# Extract only the first "percent" of rows

Tags: mysql

Imagine I'm sorting my rows based on a rating, and I want just a certain amount based on the total amount of the rows exposed (which varies every now and then, so it should be calculated on the way). Here's the subquery showing every row, and the creepy trick I tried to use with no success:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT 
        p.post_id, 
        AVG(r.numeric_rate) as numeric_rate
    FROM 
        post p 
        LEFT JOIN rating r 
            ON p.post_id = r.post_id
    WHERE 
        r.enabled > 0
    GROUP BY p.post_id
    ORDER BY numeric_rate DESC
)

LIMIT CEIL(0.10 * COUNT(*))
```

MySQL blames me in so many for doing that, that I'm a bit embarrassed. I've always done this "the PHP way", by taking the amount of rows and stopping after some fetching, but I wanted to do it "the good way", expecting a little faster response time. Could you help me solving this?

*PS: Due to some privacy policy, I can't show you the real names for fields/tables, so there might be some misspellings (though I hope not)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's not best way to solve your problem, but it's fun to work around :)

```
set @total := CEIL(0.1 * (
SELECT 
    count(distinct(post_id))
FROM 
    post p JOIN rating r ON p.post_id = r.post_id
WHERE 
    r.enabled > 0));

set @i := 0;
SELECT 
    *,
    @i:=@i+1
FROM 
    (
        SELECT p.post_id, AVG(r.numeric_rate) as numeric_rate
        FROM 
            post p JOIN rating r ON p.post_id = r.post_id
        WHERE 
            r.enabled > 0
        GROUP BY 
            p.post_id
        ORDER BY 
            numeric_rate DESC
    ) as tmp
WHERE 
    @i<@total
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, good solution. However, this doesn't consider the top 10%, but the first 10% elements to be used. The filtering should be done after the `ORDER BY` clause. As a sidenote, I tried `LIMIT @total` but it pops: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@total' at line 15 `

Comment: I updated the query to get the top 10%, please check it

Comment: Now we're talking! That's exactly the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 2 queries:

```
SELECT 
    CEIL(0.10 * COUNT(DISTINCT post_id)) as limit
FROM post
```

Use the limit:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id, 
    AVG(r.numeric_rate) as numeric_rate
FROM 
    post p 
    LEFT JOIN rating r 
        ON p.post_id = r.post_id
WHERE 
    r.enabled > 0
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY numeric_rate DESC

LIMIT :limit
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work to me. What's weirder is that it says `Undeclared variable: CEIL`

Comment: Turns out LIMIT is quite limited :) You have to use 2 queries, one to get the number of total, then the actual results. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So... I guess there's no other option than believe in an external language? Back to the ol' school methods! If you don't mind, I'll keep the accept tick for a while, just to give @HieuVo a chance to answer my comment. Oltherwise, it's yours!

Comment: If you can use multiqueries @HieuVo answer is better. Else really back to external language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two queries. One to find the percent and another one to get the rows.

```
SET @percent = 0.1; -- You cant put here your percent

SELECT round(COUNT(1) * @percent) into @limit
  FROM (
    SELECT p.post_id, avg(r.numeric_rate)
      FROM post p 
      LEFT JOIN rating r ON p.post_id = r.post_id
     GROUP BY p.post_id
  ) as tmp;

SELECT q.post_id, q.rate FROM (
    SELECT p.post_id, avg(r.numeric_rate) rate, @row := @row + 1 AS rank
      FROM post p 
      LEFT JOIN rating r ON p.post_id = r.post_id, 
      (SELECT @row := 0) row
     GROUP BY p.post_id
     ORDER BY 2 DESC
) q WHERE q.rank <= @limit;
```

I'm sure that there could be another solution more efficient, but I hope this one could works for you.

Comment: It's very useful, but you have to ensure that you querie only one record. You can use it as "select field1 into @ var1, field2 into @ var2,... " too.